# Copy-on-write style memory reuse for kubernetes pods? To make pod spawn faster and more memory efficient

Tags: kubernetes, memory, shared-memory, copy-on-write

- Can Kubernetes pods share significant amount of memory?
- Does copy-on-write style forking exist for pods?

The purpose is to make pods spawn faster and use less memory.

Our scenario is that we have a dedicated game server to host in kubernetes. The problem is that one instance of the dedicated game server would take up a few GB of memory upfront (e.g. 3 GBs).

Also, we have a few such docker images of game servers, each for game A, game B... Let's call a pod that's running game A's image for game A `pod A`.

Let's say we now have 3 x `pod A`, 5 x `pod B`. Now players rushing into game B, so I need let's say another 4 * `pod B` urgently.

I can surely spawn 4 more `pod B`. Kubernetes supports this perfectly. However there are 2 problems:

- The booting of my game server is very slow (30s - 1min). Players don't want to wait.
- More importantly for us, the cost of having this many pods that take up so much memory is very high. Because pods do not share memory as far as I know. Where as if it were plain old EC2 machine or bare metal, processes can share memory because they can fork and then copy-on-write.

Copy-on-write style forking and memory sharing seems to solve both problems.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to make pods to be able to share a "common" process of the application in the RAM, and if something is changed it should just allocate RAM only for "changed" part?

Comment: @MikolajS. Yes that's correct

Comment: Hmm, can you bake some of the initialization into the image? That would both speed up boot and reduce the memory

Comment: @JiříBaum can you suggest how I can "capture" the running state of a pod? Like in VirtualBox, I can halt the running of a VM. I don't know how I can bake an image of a running process (including its memory)

Comment: I was thinking of changing the application to do that explicitly - create a suitable file, probably also using `mmap`. If you use the right combination of parameters, you can even have mmap use the same address the second time, so even pointers will still be valid (which may be more or less helpful depending on the programming language).

Answer (score 1):

One of Kubernetes' assumptions is that *pods* are scheduled on different Nodes, which contradicts the idea of sharing common resources (does not apply for storage where [there are many options and documentation available](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/)).  The situation is different when it comes to sharing resources between *containers in one pod*, but for your issue this doesn't apply.

However, it seems that there is some possibility to share memory - not well documented and I guess very uncommon in Kubernetes. Check my answers with more details below:

> Can Kubernetes pods share significant amount of memory?

What I found is that pods can share a common [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) with the host (node).
You can check [Pod Security Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/), especially [field `hostIPC`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#host-namespaces):

> **HostIPC**  - Controls whether the pod containers can share the host IPC namespace.

Some usage examples and possible security issues [can be found here](https://github.com/BishopFox/badPods/tree/main/manifests/hostipc#bad-pod-7-hostipc):

- [Shared `/dev/sh` directory](https://github.com/BishopFox/badPods/tree/main/manifests/hostipc#inspect-devshm---look-for-any-files-in-this-shared-memory-location)
- [Use existing IPC facilities](https://github.com/BishopFox/badPods/tree/main/manifests/hostipc#look-for-any-use-of-inter-process-communication-on-the-host)

Keep in mind that this solution is not common in Kubernetes. Pods with elevated [privileges are granted broader permissions than needed](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/06/podsecuritypolicy-deprecation-past-present-and-future/#why-is-podsecuritypolicy-going-away):

> The way PSPs are applied to Pods has proven confusing to nearly everyone that has attempted to use them. It is easy to accidentally grant broader permissions than intended, and difficult to inspect which PSP(s) apply in a given situation.

That's why the Kubernetes team marked Pod Security Policies as deprecated from Kubernetes `v1.21` - [check more information in this article](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/06/podsecuritypolicy-deprecation-past-present-and-future/).

Also, if you are using multiple nodes in your cluster you [should use nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/) to make sure that pods will be assigned to same node that means they will be able to share one (host's) IPC.

> Does copy-on-write style forking exist for pods?

I did a re-search and I didn't find any information about this possibility, so I think it is not possible.

---

I think the main issue is that your game architecture is not "very suitable" for Kubernetes. Check these articles and websites about dedicated game servers in Kubernetes- maybe you will them useful:

- [Agones](https://agones.dev/site/)
- [Scaling Dedicated Game Servers with Kubernetes: Part 3 – Scaling Up Nodes](https://www.gamedeveloper.com/programming/scaling-dedicated-game-servers-with-kubernetes-part-3-scaling-up-nodes)
- [Google Cloud - Dedicated Game Server Solution](https://cloud.google.com/files/DedicatedGameServerSolution.pdf)
- [Google Cloud - Game Servers](https://cloud.google.com/game-servers)

Comment: I think the images themselves would be shared? If the initialization can be baked in, an mmap should do the trick?

Comment: Could please explain a little bit more - what do you mean by "images themselves would be shared?" Not sure what you mean, but in general yes, the pods multiple pods can be configured / started using the same image. "mmap should do the trick?" - could you explain what do you mean?

Comment: If the memory that's to be shared copy-on-write can be pre-calculated during image build, then opened using `mmap` (with `MAP_PRIVATE`) on game server start-up, there will probably only be one copy in memory across all pods (on each machine); everything in the stack _should_ be doing copy-on-write. However, it may need investigation to confirm that everything actually _is_ doing copy-on-write...

Comment: Well, I think `mmap` implementation is beyond scope of my answer ;)

Comment: Well yes. However, if the game server can be updated to work that way, it would probably be the most k8s-style solution...

Comment: Hi, can you suggest on how to "sharing resources between containers in one pod"? That might be a solution for me

Answer (score 1):

A different way to resolve the issue would be if some of the initialisation can be baked into the image.

As part of the docker image build, start up the game server and do as much of the 30s - 1min initialisation as possible, then dump that part of the memory into a file in the image. On game server boot-up, use `mmap` (with `MAP_PRIVATE` and possibly even `MAP_FIXED`) to map the pre-calculated file into memory.

That would solve the problem with the game server boot-up time, and probably also with the memory use; everything in the stack *should* be doing copy-on-write all the way from the image through to the pod (although you'd have to confirm whether it actually does).

It would also have the benefit that it's plain k8s with no special tricks; no requirements for special permissions or node selection or anything, nothing to break or require reimplementation on upgrades or otherwise get in the way. You will be able to run it on any k8s cluster, whether your own or any of the cloud offerings, as well as in your CI/CD pipeline and dev machine.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate the dumping and mmaping part? Is it correct that I just probably dump everything from the memory. And then load it backup. So I need fine control over loading of the memory. Is it correct? I need to tell my program how and where to load the needed resources. I can't just "restore" previous running state. Is that correct? Because if yes, it's going to be quite some hassle

Comment: A lot depends on what you're doing in the init and what programming language...

Comment: One way would be to mmap a file at the beginning of the init, then allocate the objects to be saved in that area of memory. On game server startup you'd then mmap it again, to the same address as before. That's for situations where you can do manual allocation relatively easily...

Comment: Another way would be to use a data store library that uses mmap internally; much easier to implement, if your data fits well into a library you can use.

Comment: A lot does depend on what it's actually doing for the 30s - 1min...

Comment: It's C++ so not all's lost. But still, modifying that part of the malloc is not going to be easy... thanks any case!

Comment: Have you profiled to see what's taking the most time in the init? If it's just one or two things, that'll be much easier to migrate than if it's dozens of different things

Comment: Modifying malloc sounds over-the-top; if the bulk of the time is calculating thousands of the same kind of thing, the mmap area can be just an array; if it's rendering thousands of tiles, you only need to put the pixbufs there (either in a predetermined order or saving the offsets and metadata in a separate file, which can be loaded normally); even if it's a mix of various different-size objects, you don't need a fancy allocator — you're never going to deallocate, so you can just start from the beginning and put the objects one after another

Comment: Also, don't forget the "library" option; you can probably get an off-the-shelf key-value store that does mmap behind the scenes, or a graph database, or various other kinds of data structures